# kohana 3.1 routing , set controller forward domain , in url

Tags: php, url, routes, kohana-3, bootstrapping

I want make such URL: `http://somecontroller.example.com` where `somecontroller` will be any controller... I am using Kohana3.1.

I know routing as well as make many routes but I haven't one such as that...

I have those default routes in bootstrap:

```
Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/page<page>)(/<id>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
                'directory'  => 'index',
        'controller' => 'main',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Kohana's routing system only allows you to parse the URI, so you can't do it in a clean way. But, you can do something like this to have your desired behaviour:

```
$controller = preg_match('/^([\w]+)\.example\.com$/', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $match)
? $match[1]
: 'main';

Route::set('default', '(<action>(/page<page>)(/<id>))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'directory'  => 'index',
        'controller' => $controller,
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

However, this routing won't work in console (`php index.php --uri=<uri>`), because `HTTP_HOST` isn't defined.

Comment: Thanks for answer... I add this code in my bootstrap but still not works... I need  exactly http://somecontroller.example.com    such URL ... No mater this will be made from bootstrap or from .htaccess  ,OR if it will be   made any other method...

Comment: With the `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`, you can change your routes to whatever you want. You just have to put a condition `if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] === 'somecontroller.example.com') { your routes while accessing your website by somecontroller.example.com } else { your routes while accessing your website by other domains }`. On your routes, don't put a controller tag, but put it in the defaults.